# css :not selector act strangely on section tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to understand how the `:not` selector works. First of all i guessed that everything that works inside of a `querySelectorAll` function works in the same way in css.

What i'm trying to accomplish is to get a list of elements from a page excluding the one i don't need. Thats's why i'm using this small function:

```
getItems() {
 return document.querySelectorAll('div:not(.sponsored):not(#hot_news) .item-story');
}
```

The important thing is that every section contain a `<li>` that has the `item-story` class, but i want to exclude the ones that are inside of a `<div>` with the class `sponsored` and a `<section>` that has the id `hot_news`.

In this fiddle you can find an example of what i tried already, it seems to work fine in CSS, but not in JS, and even if it seems to work i don't get why it should.

http://jsfiddle.net/RM8nZ/72/

Comment: `div:not(section)` is useless. A `div` element can never be a `section` element

Comment: @Oriol yes, you are right i copy-pasted an old example

Comment: Your code is working fine at my end. Are you sure that your code is not working. Maybe you need to add function keyword before getItems definition. Please look into the fiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/RM8nZ/80/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:not(foo) bar` matches all `bar` elements which have some ancestor which is not a `foo`. That does not mean that no ancestor is a `foo`.

Instead, you should get all `.item-story` elements and exclude the ones that match `.sponsored .item-story, #hot_news .item-story`.

```
var set = new Set(document.querySelectorAll('.item-story'));
var excluded = document.querySelectorAll('.sponsored .item-story, #hot_news .item-story');
for(let el of excluded) set.delete(el);
```

I used ES6 sets because operations are required to be sublinear (probably constant) on average. However, if you want to support old browsers, use arrays and see [JavaScript array difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1187518/1529630).

Comment: I was looking for a same solution actually, but using a ___filter___. http://jsfiddle.net/RM8nZ/81/
EDIT: the return value of querySelectorAll is not an Array

Comment: You have no guarantee the excluded element will be the first match, so you can't use `querySelector` in the callback. It would work properly if you used `querySelectorAll` and iterated it. But that would be a quadratic cost. ES6 sets have better performance.